# How do i run a task in ansible only if contents of a directory has been modified

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to write a task for my playbook to run a subsequent code only if changes are made to my wordpress directory. I came up with the script below however the code to redeploy the wordpress application isn't running when a change is made to the wordpress directory.

```
- name: Run if content is added or deleted in application directory
  shell: find /var/www/html/wordpress -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort -k 2 | md5sum
  register: change

- name: Copy code to application directory
unarchive:
  src:  /root/wordpress.zip
  dest: /var/www/html
  owner: apache
  group: apache
  mode: 0644
when:
  - change.stdout|success
notify:
  - Reload Apache server
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are using the shell module.
The shell module is considered a **low** level module in Ansible, meaning that it doesn't have "**Idempotence**" baked in.

So that shell command is going to run every time you run it, by default.

The way I've got it handled is that I use an **[git module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html)** for my app, and that git module then tells me if the state of my git repo is changed in relation to the state of the app that's on my production.

Example:

```
- name: Ensure demo application is at correct release.
        git:
           repo: https://github.com/foobar
           version: "{{ app_version }}"
           dest: "{{ app_directory }}"
           force: true
           accept_hostkey: true
        register: app_updated
        notify: restart nginx
```

In this example a change is only going to happen (the action that you want), when the state of the git repo is changed ( in relation to the repo thats on the server) and all the relevant actions in my playbook are going to be based on that fact.

So, you're on the right track, but I would advise you to use the **[copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html)** module, that will copy files or folders only if there is a change between your source directory and the remote directory.

And then you can catch that change with a variable (like you did), and use it later in your playbook.